# sys.time_zone_info In SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2016, database-administration

There is any place where i got all the timezone name with time zone code?
Timezone name =Pacific Standard Time,code = PST

Comment: SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I got time zone name in this query,i want timezone code like GMT,EST,SGT.

Comment: you can do it by using case when

Comment: But how i know what is the short code of 137 time zone available in  sys.time_zone_info.

Comment: Why PST? Why not PST or PDT depending on month and year?

Comment: @SalmanA i need to know that what is actual short code of all time zone available in sys.time_zone_info.

Comment: @Thebeginner there is no short code without time! My system is set to Pacific Time and dates in winter use PST and dates in summer use PDT.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the code by using case when i am just create for two you can do by yourself rest

```
SELECT case [name] when 'Easter Island Standard Time' 
                   then 'EST'
                  when 'Canada Central Standard Time' then 'CST'
                  when '' then '' end FROM sys.time_zone_info
```